# Docker run parameters in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-run

If I have a container that I run as follows:

```
docker run -d\
 --name thename\
 --restart=always\
 -p 80:80\
 -p 2003-2004:2003-2004\
 -p 8126:8126\
image_name
```

How can I create a docker file so that the container runs exactly as above without needing to specify anything but the following: `docker run -d myimage`?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot manage container name, restart policy & host ports using Dockerfile.

I would suggest you to go for docker compose. You can define all of the above in a YML file and run command such as below to get the exact behaviour which you are expecting -

`$ docker-compose up -d`

Sample YML -

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: thename
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "8126:8126"
     - "2003-2004:2003-2004"
```

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/